# how to set textview in bottom

Tags: java, android, textview

my textview display in  emulator top..how to change into the bottom...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/tv">
 <TextView 
 android:text="EmbDes Technologies"
 android:id="@+id/TextView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:textColor="#ff000000" 
 android:textStyle="bold" 
 android:gravity="bottom"/>
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/videoGrdVw" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>      
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question seems to be obscure, what i understand is that you want to align it to the bottom. Here is how you can do it:

Add the following property to your textview:

android:gravity="bottom"

Hope this helps. If it does, mark it as answered and do vote for it.

Regards.

Comment: i am already change it this...now i am post my xml file please check what mistake i made...tell..

Answer (score 0):

well, 
Button,TextView are all widget and subclasses from view
you can use textview as button easily ..
i.e. click responding:

```
TextView tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tt1);
        tt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //here I change background color when press on textviw element
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
        });
```

I hope this helps you,
if not ask exactly what are you going to do..

good luck

Mohammed,

Comment: its helpful but....i post the screenshot my text view display screen top i want to change bottom...

Answer (score 0):

using the relative layout, align one view to the top with a bottom margin equal to the height of the bottom view and align the bottom view to the bottom of the relative layout...